# Changing the color of letters doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hello everyone who can explain and help with my problem, I will be very grateful. In General, the idea is that when scrolling, when a certain part of the text becomes visible, it becomes black, and when it is not visible, it is transparent, because it does not work just when scrolling, that is, I scroll and nothing happens, only when I click again, the part that became visible is painted over.

```js
$('.way').on('click', function(){
    $('.content_side').load('way.html');
        function isVisible(elem){
            let coords = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
            let windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            let topVisible = coords.top > 0 && coords.top < windowHeight;
            let bottomVisible = coords.bottom > 0 && coords.bottom < windowHeight;
            return topVisible || bottomVisible;
        }
        function wrap(elem){
            let wrapper = document.createElement('span');
            wrapper.prepend(elem);
            elementStyle.prepend(wrapper);
        }
        let elementStyle = document.querySelector('.way_specialText');
        let text = Array.from(elementStyle.textContent.split(''));
        function finalFill(){
            elementStyle.innerHTML = '';
            text.forEach(function(item){
                wrap(item);
            });
        }
        finalFill();
        function showHidden(){
            let arraySpan = elementStyle.querySelectorAll('span');
            for(let uno of arraySpan){
                if(isVisible(uno)){
                    uno.style.color = "black";
                }
            }
        }
        showHidden()
        window.addEventListener('scroll',showHidden)
})
```

```css
.way_specialText{
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-top: 110%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke:1px black;
    transition: 0.5s all linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="way">
  <div class="way_specialText">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates placeat dicta ex, blanditiis culpa nobis amet tempore, quo quis quae neque expedita architecto dignissimos similique, enim esse odit corporis eius.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read your error message you are adding a $ sighn in the wrong place

Comment: can you tell me how to do it correctly?

Comment: I'm not really any good with jQuery but I can pass it on to a friend wo does

Comment: I will be very grateful